# Rewrite URL with grunt

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I've a app for which I need to change some url. For example `localhost:9000` should look like `localhost:9000/myapp`

All the static files will have url in html like `myapp/style/main.css`. But in actual `myapp` folder will not exist, I just need to show it in url. I don't know how to internally rewrite it.

Server is `"grunt-contrib-connect"`

Answer (score 3):

use [http-rewrite-middleware](https://github.com/viart/http-rewrite-middleware)

After you install it, put this at the top of your Gruntfile

`var rewriteModule = require('http-rewrite-middleware');`

Then under your connect livereload do something like this:

```
livereload: {
    options: {
      open: 'http://localhost:9000/myapp',
      middleware: function(connect, options, middlewares) {

        // rewrite (make sure it is first)
        middlewares.unshift(rewriteModule.getMiddleware([
          {from: '^/myapp/(.*)', to: '/$1'}
        ]));

        //paths
        middlewares.push(connect.static('.tmp'));
        middlewares.push(connect().use(
          '/bower_components',
          connect.static('./bower_components')
        ));
        middlewares.push(connect.static(appConfig.app));

        return middlewares;
      },
```

Comment: Alright, It works well. Now next problem is that static files are not loading because they are using /myapp/ in there url to load and they get a nice 404.